# Captcha redirect loses tags

Tags: bug, captcha, tag-search

When I search on CodeReview.StackExchange.com for "[f#]" (so the tag F#), I get a captcha page. After the captcha I get redirect to the search result page. This now has the query string "f#", so it lost the square brackets - suddenly I'm searching for text, not for a tag.

When I search for "[f#]" and I don't get a captcha it works as expected.

Comment: Not possible duplicate. Clearly a duplicate. :-)